# What is SubqueryAlias node in analyzed logical plan?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple sql as follows,

```
  test("SparkSQLTest") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkSQLTest").getOrCreate()
    spark.range(1, 100).createOrReplaceTempView("t1")
    val df = spark.sql("select id from t1 where t1.id = 10")
    df.explain(true)
  }
```

The output for the analyzed logical plan is:

```
 == Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
Project [id#0L]
+- Filter (id#0L = cast(10 as bigint))
   +- SubqueryAlias t1 ////don't understand here
      +- Range (1, 100, step=1, splits=Some(1))
```

Why does the SubqueryAlias show up int the logical plan? In my sql, I don't have alias related operations.

Could some one help explain? Thanks!

Comment: you have created a temporary view `.createOrReplaceTempView("t1")` and thats the alias

Comment: Thanks @RameshMaharjan. I would ask further(maybe silly), alias for what?

Comment: alias for the dataset you have created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SubqueryAlias](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L792) is an **unary logical operator** that gives an alias for the (child) subquery it was created for. The alias can be used in another part of a structured query for a correlated subquery.

`SubqueryAlias` (and aliases in general) are available until Spark Optimizer has finished query optimization phase (using [EliminateSubqueryAliases](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala#L2310) optimization rule).

Quoting [EliminateSubqueryAliases](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala#L2307-L2308) optimization:

> Subqueries are only required to provide scoping information for attributes and can be removed once analysis is complete.

In your query the subquery is the part before `createOrReplaceTempView("t1")`.

```
spark.range(1, 100).createOrReplaceTempView("t1")
```

You could rewrite the above structured query into the following that would change nothing, but gives a more elaborative explanation.

```
val q = spark.range(1, 100)
q.createOrReplaceTempView("t1")
```

So, `q` could be any other structured query and hence the need for an alias to reference any output attribute from the subquery.

---

When you `explain` the query you won't see any `SubqueryAlias` nodes (and that's not only because the logical query plan gets planned to a physical query plan where physical operators are used).